# Override top/left when child controls are streamed in

Tags: delphi, lazarus, dfm

I have a project where I try to share form files between Delphi and Lazarus. This actually works well excep with GroupBox there "top" values is caluculated against two different "tops". This menas that in Lazarus the controls are moved about 20-30 pixels too far down the TGroupBox.

Anyhow, assuming I design in Delphi, and I make a descendant TGroupBox. IO could Add a property called "fixiffromdelphi" (or something like that) and then add some code which ensures the child controls get placed correctly.

Ideally, this should happen under streamning, but I am not sure how to go about it. Is there anyway the parent (GroupBox) can access the subcontrols while the form streams in the dfm/lfm? And through that override e.g. top value?

Comment: I would probably just override the virtual `Loaded()` method, which is called after DFM streaming is finished, and have it make the necessary adjustment when compiled for Lazarus (you can use `{$IFDEF FPC}` to detect that), no need to add a new property to enable this behavior.

Comment: Just curious here... `there "top" values is caluculated against two different "tops".` Against what different tops are you seeing them calculated? I opened a Delphi-form with a TGroupbox in Lazarus and it is exactly in the same place. (Do you have a TMainMenu on top?) Also copying and pasting the component from Delphi seems fine.

Comment: Never mind... I already see what you mean. You meant the components **within** the TGroupBox which need to be adjusted. The TGroupBox in Delphi has a Top of exactly the top of the component. In Lazarus the Top of TGroupBox lies just below the line-boundary. (Just one of the small differences ;))

Comment: According to [this](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=25778.5) you'll need to adjust left too with -2 (besides the top with -16) Ideally this could/should be done in the import of Lazarus for the dfm-files.